# Python function that helps select an output based on input received (building up to a chatbot)

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements, chatbot

The overall goal of this function is to take a list of words that we got as input, a list of words to check for if they appear in the input, and a list of possible outputs to return if something from the list to check is in the input list.

I defined a function called selector with three inputs input_list, check_list, and return_list. I initialized the output to None. Next, I created a for loop to loop through the list and check that the current element of input_list is in check_list. If it is in the list, the output is assigned to a function called random.choice on the return_list.

## My code:

```
def selector(input_list, check_list, return_list):

     output = None

     for u in range(len(input_list)):
             if input_list[u] == check_list[u]:
                 output = random.choice(return_list)
        
     return output
```

The code above does not error when executed, however, I keep getting an index error when asserting my function I believe this has something to do with the conditional part of my code.

```
assert callable(selector)

assert selector(['in', 'words'], ['words'], ['yes']) == 'yes'

assert selector(['in', 'words'], ['out'], ['yes']) == None
```

---

```
IndexError                                    Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-77-e84ac970fd7f> in <module>

      1 assert callable(selector)

      2 

----> 3 assert selector(['in', 'words'], ['words'], ['yes']) == 'yes'

      4 assert selector(['in', 'words'], ['out'], ['yes']) == None

<ipython-input-76-2445f1f5eac9> in selector(input_list, check_list, return_list)
      3     output = None
      4     for u in range(len(input_list)):
----> 5         if input_list[u] == check_list[u]:
      6             output = random.choice(return_list)
      7 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely because `input_list` has more elements than `check_list`

I suspect you're looking for something more like this (not tested):

```py
def selector(input_list, check_list, return_list):

    for item in check_list:
        if item in input_list:
            return random.choice(return_list)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = ['in', 'words']
check_list = ['words']
```

Different length causes `IndexError` in `if input_list[u] == check_list[u]:` if `u == 1`, here's a way to fix it (I'm assuming all words in `check_list` must be in `input_list`):

```
def selector(input_list, check_list, return_list):
     flag = True
     input_list = set(input_list)
     for i in check_list:
         if i not in input_list: 
             flag = False
     if flag:
         return random.choice(return_list)
     else:
         return None
     return output
```